# Slim ASP.NET based portal framework

Tags: asp.net, portal

I am looking for a (very) **lightweigted portal framework**, which is based on ASP.NET. 
I know there systems like **"DNN"**, **"Umbraco"** or **"Sharepoint Foundation 2010"**. But these frameworks seem to me a little bit too heavy and swollen.
What are good and slim alternatives (free use for commercial purposes) ? The framework should provide at least provide support for navigation,  **authentication** and basic **CMS**. And it should be possible to **integrate other aspx pages** (applications) in webparts or similar containers.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? There might be some options depending upon your exact need.

Comment: You dismiss Umbraco but suggest SharePoint Foundation as a possible alternative?  I can't begin to tell you what is wrong with that...

Comment: You might have to "roll your own".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about "Kooboo" ?
-->  http://kooboo.codeplex.com/

or "Mojoportal"
--> http://www.mojoportal.com/

Answer (score 1):

I think that Umbraco actually seems quite lightweight I don't think you should dismiss it on grounds of being to heavy.